# Routing changes after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having a difficult time navigating using MVC after deploying to a server. Everything works fine on Localhost, but here is my situation:

when using localhost my urls look like this:

```
http://localhost:64407/Home/Index
```

When I deploy to my intranet server with the application name "wfm" my urls look like this:

```
http://vm-pcm01/wfm/Home/Index
```

The initial view loads fine, but if I go to return another view after submitting a form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Signup(SignupForm SignupForm)
{
    return View("FormSubmitted");
}
```

This directs me to the url:

```
http://vm-pcm01/Home/Index
```

which gives me a  404. I am seriously stumped as I thought that returning a view would be relative to the application path in IIS... this works fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Actually.  I see you call SignupForm but dont use it.

> ```
>     return View("FormSubmitted", SignupForm);
> ```

Comment: that was actually the first thing I tried, but then the initial view is wfm/wfm/home/index which doesnt exist. The initial view loads correctly, but any views that are being returned from a form submit are not working. I basically just have a form where the user fills out info and submits it then it returns a view that says "thank you" with a link back to the homepage. Can't get the "thank you' view to come up after deployment (works on localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, good point I do need that so I can access the object data. Specific to the URL routing though it turns out that I jumped the gun and was careless. I had to set the "action" attribute of the form to a url action of my post :

```
@Url.Action("PostForm","Home")
```

I still had it set to be "Home/PostForm" which was getting me nowhere'

that in turn redirects it to the form submitted action and it works properly

sorry about that